# $\phi:G\to \bar G$ is an isomorphism. Then the equation $x^k=b$ has the same number of solutions in $G$ as the equation $x^k=\phi(b)$ in $\bar G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism

This is my first post here, so forgive for any formatting errors or lack of information; please let me know if I can rectify any issue with my post.

I've been stuck on this problem for quite a bit, and I was wondering if my solution had any merit. Here's what I have:

*Proof:* Let $X = \{x \in G:x^k = b\}$ for some fixed integer $k$ and fixed element $b \in G$ and $Y = \{y \in \bar G|y^k = \phi(b) \in \bar G\}$.

Then $\forall x \in X$, we have that $(\phi(x))^k = \phi(x^k) = \phi(b) \implies \phi(x) \in Y \implies \phi(X) \subseteq Y$.

Similarly, $\forall y \in Y$, we have that $y = \phi(\phi^{-1}(y)) \implies \phi(b) = \phi(\phi^{-1}(y)^k) \implies b = (\phi^{-1}(y))^k \implies y \in \phi(X) \implies Y \subseteq \phi(X)$.

Then $\phi(X) = Y$. Because $\phi$ is an isomorphism, then $|X| = |\phi(X)|$.

Please let me know if I have made any errors as abstract algebra is definitely not my strong suit. Thank you!

Comment: The way you define $X$ means that $X=G$. I think you want $k$ and $b$ be fixed, right?

Comment: Ah, yeah, that was an error. Thank you!

Comment: in the title the group is $G'$, but in the body it's $\bar{G}$. Otherwise the argument is correct.

Comment: Okay great, thank you so much!

Comment: I am not sure by what is $|X|$. Is the group supposed to be finite?

Comment: $|X|$ defines the set of solutions to the equation $x^k = b$ for some fixed integer $k$ and fixed group element $b \in G$; I would assume this set to be finite even for infinite groups?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you essentially got it.

If $x^k=b$ then $\phi(x^k)=\phi(b)\Rightarrow (\phi(x))^k=\phi(b)$ so $\phi(x)\in Y$ for all $x\in X$. Thus $|Y|\geq |X|$ (since $\phi$ is injective).

Also, $y^k=\phi(b)\Rightarrow (\phi(a))^k=\phi(b)$ for some $a\in G$ (since $\phi$ is surjective)

$\Rightarrow \phi(a^k)=\phi(b)$

$\Rightarrow \phi^{-1}(\phi(a^k))=\phi^{-1}(\phi(b))$

$\Rightarrow a^k=b$

$\Rightarrow a\in X$ so $|Y|\leq |X|$ (since $\phi$ is injective).